# Is possible to simplify this multiple linux command script (maybe awk commands)?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

To guess what's happening with some KDE applications doing weird things, I created a one line command to have a list of all files that are not located by a desktop application when I just launch and close it.

I use `strace` output as source of data to be processed, as lines below:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-rc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No existe el fichero o el directorio)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/.uuid", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No existe el fichero o el directorio)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/cache/fontconfig/0bcde688-f6c6-45d7-9a5c-9a93ce4e186f-x86_64.cache-7", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No existe el fichero o el directorio)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/platformthemes/KDEPlasmaPlatformTheme.so.avx2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No existe el fichero o el directorio)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-rc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No existe el fichero o el directorio)
```

I want to get a list of all not found files/folders in a text row and I got it with:

```
strace **DAN** 2>&1 | awk -v FS="," '/openat/ && /No existe/ {print substr($2, 3, length($2) - 3)} ' | sort | uniq -u | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"; ORS=" "} {print $NF}'
```

where **DAN** is a desktop application name as "kate", "libreoffice" or anyone.

*Note: /No existe/ is like /Doesn't exist/ or /Not found/*

I'm sure that this command could be simplified, avoiding two "awk" commands, but don't know how. I use "sort" and "uniq" cause I don't want repeated filenames.

Anyone could simplify this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: For starters, `strace -e trace=openat`. `could simplify this?` What for? Why do you want it "simplified"? Doesn't it work as it is?

Comment: please update the question with the expected output

Comment: KamilCuk, mine it works "like it", but as I'm not familiar with "awk" command and even pipelines, I was sure there are better ways to do what I got, for clarity and speed, and I was not able to do it  better.

Comment: Supposedly, my statement did what I wanted: Return filenames not found. However, after your answers, I realized that something was not working after adding my second "awk" command and no matter how much I changed the order, even putting " | sort | uniq -u " at the end instead of in the middle of my statement, duplicate filenames appear!!!.  That has shown me that something is missing and that I have done well to consult here people who clearly master "[g]awk". Thank you all, your solutions are the ones that really work, not mine (it's like "uniq -u" doesn't work in my statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file names do not contain double quotes and the only double quotes in the matching lines are around the file name, you could use the double quotes as field separator, rework `$2` and use the result as the key of an associative array (for the uniqueness):

```
$ strace **DAN** 2>&1 | awk -F'"' '
    /^openat.*No existe/ {sub(/(.*\/)?/,"",$2); f[$2]}
    END {for(k in f) printf("%s ", k); print}'
.uuid 0bcde688-f6c6-45d7-9a5c-9a93ce4e186f-x86_64.cache-7 nvidia-application-profiles-rc KDEPlasmaPlatformTheme.so.avx2
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct. The output of "trace" only quotes the "paths + filenames" strings. Your resolution seems to me a very clever way to simplify not only my use of two "awk" commands, but to eliminate additional commands that I used in my statement.  In fact, like JNevill does, with your statement it is unnecessary to use the "sort" and "uniq" commands.

I would only need to modify the "print" parameter so that the output is separated by spaces instead of lines. Thank you very much.

Comment: To separate with spaces just replace `for(k in f) print k` by `for(k in f) printf("%s ", k); print`. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you again Renaud, really I was mad trying to figure how to get it. I tried  "strace **DAN**  2>&1 | awk -F'"' ' /^openat.*No existe/ {sub(/(.*\/)?/,"",$2); f[$2]} END {ORS=" "} {for(k in f) print k}' but result was dozens of repeated lines .

Answer (score 1):

I kind of like your implementation as it's easy to understand. Doing this entirely in awk (or gawk in this case) would get a little muddy. Something like:

```
gawk -v FS="[,\"]" '/openat/ && /No existe/ {paths[gensub(/.*\//, "", 1, $3)]} END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";for(path in paths){printf("%s ",path)};print}'
```

Essentially this is just dumping out the application name into the key of an associative array. This allows us to dedup since you can't have two keys with the same index.

Once the strace output is fully parsed we tell gawk to sort the array using its key, sorting by string (lexicographically), and in ascending order.

Then we iterate over the array and print out the key.

Like I said though, if I were writing this to be a supportable application, I would go with your implementation. The steps are clear in the processing and there isn't any funny business, like borrowing the deduping of associated array keys to mimic your `uniq` as an example.

Comment: I must say you explained it perfectly and works BETTER than mine. I compared results and noticed mine have repeated results (that didn't happen when I make my first version, I should check it). I never used "gawk" and must take a look to it. The ONLY issue (in my Linux at least) is that it adds a line "+++ exited with 0 +++" but really I don't know to avoid it.

Comment: Chances are, on linux, your `awk` command is using `gawk` or `nawk` under the hood. You can look at the awk version to confirm. I was using a mac to write this where the unflavored`awk` is installed by default.

Comment: My Linux is using "Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0". In fact, I accidentally noticed that text ("+++ exited +++")  come from "strace" output.  Despite  that's why finally it appears in result output, cause. Even though supposedly the output of "strace" is filtered and shouldn't show that additional text, it eventually "sneaks in" as part of the result in your statement. It's not a serious problem, so I can leave it at that. Thank you very much for all the information and your opinion.